# Using Aura lightning:datatable to show related list?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, related-list

I am attempting to use Aura lightning:datatable to make a Case related list in the Account object but I can't figure out how to properly query the ID of the Account.

As it is now, I'm just doing a general query of all Cases and displaying that. I don't know how to be able to specify in my query *Where AccountId =: Id*, but I don't know how to properly set it up for that. If I just add that to the query it will give me an error saying 'Variable does not exist :Id'.

Here are my pieces...

**My Apex controller :**

```
public class DatatableHandler {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getCases(){
        return [SELECT Id,CaseNumber,CreatedDate,Status,Reason,Subject,LastModifiedDate 
                FROM Case Where AccountId =: Id ];           
    }    
 }
```

**My component (DatatableHandler) :**

```
<aura:component controller="DatatableHandler" 
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" 
                access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="results" type="Case[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">             
            <lightning:datatable keyField="id" data="{!v.results}"
                                 columns="{!v.mycolumns}"
                                 resizeColumnDisabled="true"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"                          
                                />            
        </lightning:layoutItem>       
    </lightning:layout>   
 </aura:component>
```

**My js controller (LinkInDatatableController) :**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Date Opened', fieldName: 'CreatedDate',type: 'date',sortable:true,
             typeAttributes:{day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric',hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit',hour12:true}},
            {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject',type: 'text'},
            {label: 'CASE Name', fieldName: 'linkName',type: 'url', 
             typeAttributes:{label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber' }, target: '_blank'}},            
            {label: 'Last Modified Date', fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate',type: 'date',sortable:true,
             typeAttributes:{day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric',hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit',hour12:true}},
            {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status',type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Case Reason', fieldName: 'Reason',type: 'text'}
            
            
        ]);
        var action=component.get("c.getCases");
        action.setCallback(this,function(e){            
            if(e.getState()=='SUCCESS'){
                var results=e.getReturnValue(); 
                console.log(results);
                if(results.length>0){
                    results.forEach(function(record){
                        record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
                    });
                    component.set('v.results', results);                                          
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },    
 })
```

I would really appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively common use case so the following points should help.

First of all, you need to update your Apex controller method to accept a parameter for you to pass the Record Id to, and then use that variable in your SOQL query like this:

```
public class DatatableHandler {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getCases(String accountId){
        return [SELECT Id,CaseNumber,CreatedDate,Status,Reason,Subject,LastModifiedDate 
                FROM Case  WHERE AccountId = :accountID];           
    }    
 }
```

When calling this method, you'll now need to pass that parameter in like the following:

```
var action=component.get("c.getCases");
action.setParamaters({ accountId : component.get("v.recordId"));
```

You've already implemented the `force:hasRecordId` interface in your component which will ensure that the component is aware of it's context so that is good.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much Callum ! I really appreciate it ! btw - do you happen to know a quick way to make those columns sortable ? I know simply labeling them sortable:true doesn't do it.

Comment: No worries at all! For sorting, there's a pretty good explanation about what you need to do under the 'Sorting Data By Column' section of the lightning:datatable component documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation but feel free to raise another question if that doesn't cover what you need.

Comment: Thanks again Callum. I've managed to put something together for the sorting using some function and a Helper. But I can't get it to run properly. I've been hacking at it for about two hours now. I'm gonna put in a question, but I don't want to derail your awesome help on here so I'll put another one in. Thanks again for all of your help here !